# how to smooth pixelated grids on a map plot produced by ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a global map that are produced by ggplot. My problem is that the grids on the map seem too 'pixelated' (1.1*1.1 degree scale). I would like to know how to smooth out the grid edge so that they look more 'blended' with the surrounding grids.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEmEf.png)
Thank you in advance.

Below is the code to reproduce my problem:

```
lengthmap <-
  ggplot() +
  geom_map( data = wrld,
            map=wrld,
            aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=region),
            color="black",
            size=0.05,
            fill="gray97") +
  coord_proj("+proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs",
             ylim=c(-25,55),
             xlim=c(-25,130))+
  theme_minimal()+
  expand_limits(x = world$long, y = world$lat)+
  geom_tile(data = data,aes(X1, X2, fill = X4),alpha = 0.8)+
  scale_fill_fermenter(breaks=c(1, 3, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60), palette = "Spectral") +
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(ticks = TRUE, even.steps = FALSE)) +
  xlab("Longitude") +
  ylab("Latitude") +
  theme(legend.key.width = unit(0.1, 'in'),
        legend.key.height = unit(0.7, 'in'),
        legend.position = 'right',
        plot.title = element_text(size=10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the geometry, probably `geom_raster` will give a better result than `geom_tile`, here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
```

### geom_tile

```
 ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions)) +
   geom_tile(aes(fill = density))+
   scale_fill_viridis_c()
```

[image: geom_tile example]

### geom_raster

```
 ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions)) +
   geom_raster(aes(fill = density), interpolate = TRUE)+
   scale_fill_viridis_c()
```

[image: geom_raster example]

Comment: Thanks for the quick advice! I tried what you suggested, but an error occurred.           Error: geom_raster only works with Cartesian coordinates
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
1: Raster pixels are placed at uneven horizontal intervals and will be shifted. Consider using geom_tile() instead. 
2: Raster pixels are placed at uneven vertical intervals and will be shifted. Consider using geom_tile() instead.